# how to fill in the value in the array

Tags: javascript, actionscript-3, flash

i have code like this in actionscript3,

```
var map: Array = [
                  [[0,1,0],[0,1,0]],
                  [[0,1,0], [0,1,0]]]; 
var nom1: int = 0;
var nom2: int = 0;
var nom3: int = 1;
var nom4: int = 18;
stage.addEventListener (Event.ENTER_FRAME, beff);
function beff (e: Event): void
{
  map[nom1][nom2][nom3] = nom4
}
stage.addEventListener (MouseEvent.CLICK, brut);
function brut(e: MouseEvent):void 
{
 trace (map)
}
```

when run, it gets an error in its output

what I want is to fill in each "1" value and not remove the "[" or "]" sign

so when var nom1, var nom2 are changed

Then the output is

```
[[[0,18,0],[0,18,0]],
 [[0,18,0],[0,18,0]]]
```

please helps for those who can solve this problem

Comment: Please share what kind of error do you get there. I did a simplified test with the original **map** of yours and **map[0][0][1] = 18;** line, still it went just fine and produced the expected result.

Comment: sorry, what I mean is to add the var map depth level for "i" and "j" (var nom1 and var nom2),because when I change the values ​​in "var nom1" and "var nom2" to higher values, it happens an error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If what you want to achieve is to replace every 1 by 18 in this nested array, you could try :

```
for (var i = 0; i < map.length; i++) {
    var secondLevel = map[i];
    for (var j = 0; j < secondLevel.length; j++) {
        var thirdLevel = secondLevel[j];
        for (var k = 0; k < thirdLevel.length; k++) {
            if (thirdLevel[k] === 1) {
                thirdLevel[k] = 18;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Note that, this would only work for nested arrays with 3 levels of depth

Comment: The **for each** loops for two outer loops will make the script shorter.

Comment: Also, **thirdLevel[k] === 18;** is a comparison, not an assignment. It won't change the data in the **map**.

Comment: sorry, what I mean is to add the var map depth level for "i" and "j" (var nom1 and var nom2),because when I change the values ​​in "var nom1" and "var nom2" to higher values, it happens an error